# Django Heroku postgres connectivity error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, wagtail

I'm trying to push a basic Wagtail Django site (`pip install wagtail`) to Heroku following [this guide](https://wagtail.io/blog/deploying-wagtail-heroku/) with guidance from [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) and I am getting a very common postgres connectivity error (below). I can see from the dashboard that Heroku is providing the live database, and I can access it with `heroku pq:psql`.

The project runs locally and also when I run `heroku local`.

My `project/app/settings/production.py' is set up as recommended:

```
import os

env = os.environ.copy()
SECRET_KEY = env['SECRET_KEY']

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .base import *

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
print('check')
print(DATABASES)

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

`Procfile` (at root of repo)

```
web: gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

`myproj/wsgi.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings.dev")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The error I get:

```
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: That settings file has some print statements; are they visible in the logs? If not it's a clue that that file isn't being picked up at all.

Comment: Yes, I put them there to check that, but I'm not clear where I should expect to see them i.e. where settings would naturally be called. `heroku logs` doesn't show full logging info and the traceback that my error's in (which I posted some of) makes no mention of trying to access settings. Where would I look? Thanks!

Comment: I've just noticed that your settings is called production.py. How have you told Django to use that file? Show your Procfile and wsgi.py.

Comment: I've added those to my question. A lot of this is Wagtail boilerplate: https://pypi.org/project/wagtail/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wsgi file is pointing to your dev settings; the production ones are not being used at all.

Using `setdefault` to set the environment variable means that an existing value will be used in preference if it is already set. So you should run `heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproj.settings.production` to set that value.